# Append pandas column values as new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes in pandas shown below.

```
   a  b  c    d
0  1  1  1  0.1
1  1  1  2  0.4
2  1  2  1  0.2
3  1  2  2  0.5


   a  b   c1   c2
0  1  1  0.1  0.4
1  1  2  0.2  0.5
```

I am wondering how I can turn the first dataframe into the second one?
I tried using pivot_table, but I was not sure how to specify retaining columns a and b, in addition to using the values from c to make new columns. I also tried using groupby and unstack, but that created a hierarchical column index for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is important if values first columns in `set_index` are unique.

Then use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) column `c`, [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = (df.set_index(['a','b','c'])['d']
        .unstack()
        .add_prefix('c')
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
   a  b   c1   c2
0  1  1  0.1  0.4
1  1  2  0.2  0.5
```

If first 3 columns are duplicated need aggregate by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregate function like `mean`, `sum`... and then solution is same as before or use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
print (df)
   a  b  c    d
0  1  1  1  0.1 <- 1,1,1
1  1  1  2  0.4
2  1  2  1  0.2
3  1  2  2  0.5
4  1  1  1  0.7 <- 1,1,1

df = (df.groupby(['a','b','c'])['d']
        .mean()
        .unstack()
        .add_prefix('c')
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

Or:

```
df = (df.pivot_table(index=['a','b'], columns='c', values='d')
        .add_prefix('c')
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

---

```
print (df)
   a  b   c1   c2
0  1  1  0.4  0.4
1  1  2  0.2  0.5
```